# Process Collection of XML objects returned from a restful webservice in java

Tags: java, rest, webservice-client

I have a restful web service that return a collection of employees but i don't know how to process this returned data. I know if it were to be a single object that was returned i could unmarshal it and cast to my desire class but how do i do that and save my data in a list, arraylist, set or any other form of collection.

```
//single object (perfect)
Customer c = (Customer) jc.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(xml);

// Error
List<Customer> list = (List<Customer>) jc.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(xml);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
@XmlRootElement
class Customer {
    @XmlElement
    String name;
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}

@XmlRootElement
class Customers {
    @XmlElement(name = "customer")
    List<Customer> list;
}

class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String xml = "<customers><customer><name>Ayodeji</name></customer></customers>";
        JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customers.class);
        Unmarshaller um = ctx.createUnmarshaller();
        Customers res = (Customers)um.unmarshal(new StringReader(xml));
        System.out.println(res.list);
    }
}
```

output

```
[Ayodeji]
```

Comment: I did exactly as you said, created the wrapper class but i still have the same error; 

Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"customers"). Expected elements are <{}customer>,<{}discountCode>,<{}microMarket>

Comment: Can you add an example of xml to your question?

Comment: This is some of the xml returned by the webservice

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
   <customers> 
       <customer> 
            <name>JumboCom</name> 
           <email>jumbocom@gmail.com</email> 
           <fax>305-777-4635</fax> 
       </customer>
       <customer> 
            <name>Ayodeji</name> 
           <email>ayo@gmail.com</email> 
           <fax>305-777-4444</fax> 
       </customer>  
   </customers>

Comment: Now its working. I even passed the whole collection of objects from the webservice and it worked. Thanks